# Angular Flex Layout refuses to center container horizontally, applied directives to div, router outlet, everything, yet it still wont center

Tags: css, angular, flexbox, angular-material, angular-flex-layout

Recording of the elements insepcted: https://streamable.com/nmhaa

The container within 'interactive-models' will simple not center inside his parent container.

in App Component Html:

```
<router-outlet fxLayout="column" fxFlexAlign="center" fxLayoutAlign="center center">
```

Inside Interactive-models commponent.html:

```
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center center"
```

fxHide.lt-md="true" class="container theStupidList" fxFlex="90%">

The Material grid list:

```
<mat-grid-list class="item" fxFlex="90" fxFlexAlign="center"  
cols="3" rowHeight="600" gutterSize="15px">
```

In my CSS:

```
.theStupidList {
justify-content: center!important;
justify-self:center !important;
justify-items: center!important; }
```

Comment: stackblitz or plunkr?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I may be wrong here, but the component that you’re trying to display inside the router isn’t actually outlet’s child (it’s would be a sibling) if you look in the DOM. Therefore you need to flex the parent that holds the outlet. Just wrap the outlet in a div and center the the children.

```
<div fxLayout=“row” fxLayoutAlign=“center center”>
```

If you would like you can also set the fxFlexFill on that parent div to make sure it take the whole available space

Comment: Ah, this works but now the grid list won't display no matter if I set that div that's the parent of router outlet as column or row. I've also removed the div parent from the interactive component and removed all directives from material grid list and it still won't display/give an error. The grid list element is a complete nightmare.

Comment: Would you be able to provide the error message? Maybe replace your grid with a super simple one like this: 
<mat-grid-list cols="1" rowHeight="1:1">
  <mat-grid-tile>Test</mat-grid-tile>
</mat-grid-list>
 to see if it's a problem with a grid or something else

Comment: Just did --  there's no error whatsoever, it simply does not show up. Tested it with the test grid list and same behaviour. You did however answer the original question and that was solved so thanks! Now it seems the problem I'm having is specific to material grid list.